# How to digitize infrared slides for use in GIS?

Tags: digital-image-processing

I have an aerial infrared slide with the following dimensions 20cm x 30cm. It was captured with an infrared camera from a height of around 3000m a few years back and now my environmental agency would like to digitize it for further analysis in GIS. I have until now had no experience with either infrared imagery or digitization of slides so the first thing I did was to put in into our flatbed scanner and see what came out. The image is dark! By manipulating histograms of the red/blue/green channels using The Gimp I can create a few outlines and increase detail a bit, but it is really still showing nothing.

Can anyone put me on the right track as to either how to scan this sort of document or how to manipulate the pixels using photoshop or similar software?

A few pictures to set the context are below:

- 600dpi Scan without manipulation

[image: 600dpi Scan without manipulation]

- With pixel manipulation

[image: With pixel manipulation]

Comment: Is this color infrared (like 4 band NAIP imagery), or truly just infrared? If it's just infrared I'd think you'd want a grey scale image rather than RGB, since you are only interested in intensities. If not....I have no idea how you would scan such a thing.

Comment: I don´t have any information about the  specifications assignment unfortunately. If I assume that it is color infrared, what could I do to make a useful image out of it?